# How can go back to the top of my code without using loop?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a "Flames" program and my problem is after the user enters his/her name accompanied with the partners name and gets the result i want to ask the user if they want to enter another name without using loop .

I've tried using goto but then errors occur where the user cant enter the initial name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
  start:
  system("cls");
  char t;
  string fname1,fname2;
  int i,x,z,y,name1len=0,name2len=0,b,total,name1spc=0,name2spc=0;

  cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
  getline(cin,fname1);
  cout<<"Enter partners name: ";
  getline(cin,fname2);
  cout<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<=fname1.length();i++ )
        {

        fname1[i]=toupper(fname1[i]);

        }    
    for(i=0;i<=fname2.length();i++)    
        {

        fname2[i]=toupper(fname2[i]);
        }


 x=fname1.length();
 y=fname2.length();



//============check for spaces=========


        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(fname1[i]==' ')
                {
                name1spc++;
                }

        }
        for(i=0;i<y;i++)
        {
            if(fname2[i]==' ')
                {
                name2spc++;
                }

        }

//=========for 1st name compare=========
  for(i=0;i<fname1.length();i++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<fname2.length();b++)
            {
            //cout<<fname1[i]<<endl;
                if(fname1[i]==fname2[b])
                    {
                    name1len++;
                    break;

                    }

            }

    }
 //============2nd name compare================
 for(i=0;i<fname2.length();i++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<fname1.length();b++)
            {
            //cout<<fname1[i]<<endl;
                if(fname2[i]==fname1[b])
                    {
                    name2len++;
                    break;

                    }

            }

    }





  name1len=name1len-name1spc;
  name2len=name2len-name2spc;
  cout<<name1len<<endl<<name2len;


  total=name1len+name2len;

  if(total>6)
  {
  total=total%6;
  }

  switch(total)
  {

 case 1:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Friends"<<endl;
 break;
 case 2:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Lovers"<<endl;
 break;
 case 3:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Aquaintance"<<endl;
 break;
 case 4:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Married"<<endl;
 break;
 case 5:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Enemies"<<endl;
 break;
 case 6:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Sweethearts"<<endl;
 break;
 default:
 cout<<"No name entered"<<endl;
 } 

  cout<<"Would you like to enter another name? Y/N?";
  cin>>t;

     if(t=='Y' || t=='y')
       {
        goto start;
        }
     else if(t=='N' || t=='n')
       {
        cout<<"THANKS"<<endl;
        system("pause");
       }
      else{
       return 0;
          }









   }//ending for int main
```

Comment: *I've tried using goto* -- Why?  A loop is the structured way to do this.

Comment: Have you considered using a [do-while loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)?

Comment: I added the whole code so you could see what i meant.

Comment: Really a loop is the right tool for the job here.  Unless you have some explicit reason not to use one (e.g. you're doing this for an assignment that forbids the usage of loops as an exercise), this is like trying to make a sandwich without using bread :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use while loop like below:

```
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
  while(true){
  system("cls");
  char t;
  string fname1,fname2;
  int i,x,z,y,name1len=0,name2len=0,b,total,name1spc=0,name2spc=0;

  cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin,fname1);
  cout<<"Enter partners name: ";
  getline(cin,fname2);
  cout<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<=fname1.length();i++ )
        {

        fname1[i]=toupper(fname1[i]);

        }    
    for(i=0;i<=fname2.length();i++)    
        {

        fname2[i]=toupper(fname2[i]);
        }


 x=fname1.length();
 y=fname2.length();



//============check for spaces=========


        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(fname1[i]==' ')
                {
                name1spc++;
                }

        }
        for(i=0;i<y;i++)
        {
            if(fname2[i]==' ')
                {
                name2spc++;
                }

        }

//=========for 1st name compare=========
  for(i=0;i<fname1.length();i++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<fname2.length();b++)
            {
            //cout<<fname1[i]<<endl;
                if(fname1[i]==fname2[b])
                    {
                    name1len++;
                    break;

                    }

            }

    }
 //============2nd name compare================
 for(i=0;i<fname2.length();i++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<fname1.length();b++)
            {
            //cout<<fname1[i]<<endl;
                if(fname2[i]==fname1[b])
                    {
                    name2len++;
                    break;

                    }

            }

    }





  name1len=name1len-name1spc;
  name2len=name2len-name2spc;
  cout<<name1len<<endl<<name2len;


  total=name1len+name2len;

  if(total>6)
  {
  total=total%6;
  }

  switch(total)
  {

 case 1:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Friends"<<endl;
 break;
 case 2:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Lovers"<<endl;
 break;
 case 3:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Aquaintance"<<endl;
 break;
 case 4:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Married"<<endl;
 break;
 case 5:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Enemies"<<endl;
 break;
 case 6:
 cout<<fname1<<" and "<<fname2<<" are Sweethearts"<<endl;
 break;
 default:
 cout<<"No name entered"<<endl;
 } 

  cout<<"Would you like to enter another name? Y/N?";
  cin>>t;

     if(t=='Y' || t=='y')
       {
        continue;
        }
     else if(t=='N' || t=='n')
       {
        cout<<"THANKS"<<endl;
        break;
       }
      else{
       return 0;
          }
   } //while end









   }//ending for int main
```

Comment: now the problem is i cant enter the 1st name, it skips to the partners name.

Comment: use cin.ignore(); after printing "Enter your full name: ". I have updated the code in my answer, check that. The problem with getline is that it stores the previos input in cin object and to ignore that previous input we have to use cin.ignore() function.

Comment: The `<=` tests should all be `<` here. @OP Why did you accept this answer when you stated you didn't want to use a loop?